# Is it discrimination to hold someone from a minority or underprivileged background to the same academic standard as regular students?

Tags: graduate-school, supervision, inclusivity

Suppose a graduate student is found to be noticeably or even significantly behind in overall academic and research competence. For example, they may have significantly weaker language and comprehension skills and technical skills such as using a computer or navigating the web. They may also be lacking other peripheral skills which are often important for graduate students. This may be indirectly related to being from a minority and/or underprivileged background where such exposure and opportunities to learn can be limited.

If he/she are held to the same standards as his/her peers when comparing their relative performance, would this be considered to be discrimination if his/her situation was known? On one hand, same treatment would be fair to his/her peers and avoids human judgement. On the other hand, one could argue that it is unreasonable to expect the same amount of performance when they are missing necessary skills and experience.

There was a comment that 'held to the same standards' was too vague. As a result I want to provide some hypothetical situations in which it is necessary to compare the performance of a student with his/her peers.

Suppose an advisor has limited funding for RA and travel opportunities. They want to provide them to students with the best performance either as a means of rewarding them or to provide a better return on investment. This would mean the graduate student in question would have little chance of obtaining it. Is this discrimination or an unfair bias?

Suppose again the average graduation time for a program is 5 years. However, due to the slow progress of the student (compared to their peers) they may be held for 6 or 7 years before being deemed ready to graduate. Is this a discriminatory practice?

Comment: Maybe the question should be, do you have an opportunity to assist them to help themselves improve. Is there a way you can help them mitigate their (and others) limitations without changing your grading of their work? E.g., maybe encourage them to join a study group or refer them to a language course.

Comment: What does "held to the same standards" mean, in graduate school (e.g., I'm thinking of mathematics). Is this about "grading"? Is there any reason to "compare" individuals? Do you have some obligation to "fail" a certain fraction? The context is very unclear.

Comment: @paulgarrett I've made some additions

Comment: I don't think you've asked the question you actually want to ask, because "Suppose a graduate student is ... significantly behind in overall academic and research competence. ... This could plausibly be due to being a minority" is the textbook definition of a racist comment. I presume you didn't mean to imply that students' ethnicity determines or affects their language comprehension or academic ability. So why don't you take the time to rewrite your question to ask what you actually meant?

Comment: @TomChurch I am asking the question I mean to ask. I've changed the sentence to be more specific but the point remains. No, I am not implying being a minority affects prevents one from learning at the same rate. Being from a minority background can however affect their language comprehension ability as English can be a third or even fourth language.

Comment: @Co3O4: This is one of those cases where people really *really* care that you don't appear to mix up correlation and causation: it's not that the ethnicity itself affects language comprehension ability in general. Rather, it's that the language you grow up with at home/school affects your ability to comprehend other *particular* languages differently (i.e. you'll understand more similar ones to your native language more easily than more foreign ones). It's an obvious fact, but many people will completely flip out when you don't word it carefully.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too broad and more about political theory, ethics, and/or legal philosophy than academia.

Comment: Using different standards can have two negative side-effects: it can turn some of the "underprivileged" into slobs (why should I work more if I will pass just because of my status?) and it can turn some of the majority group into racists (how come they got a better grade despite performing worse than me?)

Comment: @Co3O4: Though I agree with your intention more than Tom Church's interpretation, to avoid this ambiguity, it might be better to say that it is _**indirectly**_ related to them being a minority (i.e. their race doesn't directly cause their lack of comprehension; but their race can be a cause for social disadvantages which in turn can cause a lack of comprehension)

Comment: Although I voted to close as unclear what you're asking, I do encourage you to edit your question to make it clearer.  Are you asking about ethics or law?  (Hint: you are permitted to ask more than one question at this site.)  If you're asking about law, it's important to specify the country.  The US law about this is clear and has been written about here to some extent; but I would love to see more information written up here for other countries.

Comment: I think you have to consider the whole.  If I were to be judged on my web-using skills, for instance, I'd be well at the bottom of the class, but that really has nothing to do with my ability to translate science into usable programs.  Or FTM to copy-edit everyone else's papers.

Comment: FWIW, this is the exact reason why countries like India have *Reservations* to make "discrimination" apparent. Everything goes downhill from there. IMHO - one "should" hold everyone to the same *intellectual standard* - not knowing tools/techniques are trivial and lack of exposure to it shouldn't be the reason to consider one as "intellectually inferior". That's my rule of thumb in situations like this.

Comment: [Meta post about on-topicness of this question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3994/10646)

Comment: Its discriminatory to hold anyone to a different standard. It doesnt matter how handicapped they are.  If a minority cannot succeed on merit alone then it in fact validates racism as scientifically based.  Quotas that supposedly serve the minority do more harm, by discriminating against the majority, by pushing people into situations they are ill-prepared for, and by affirming that merit is not sufficient for their success and so are not fundamentally equally capable.

Comment: This should be two separate questions. Is it discriminatory to hold minority students to different academic standards or to give them extra help? Absolutely.  Is it discriminatory to hold someone from an underprivileged background to a different academic standard? The better thing to do would be to try to arrange extra help to help them overcome deficits arising from their previous educational environment.

Answer (score 84):

You are asking two separate and completely unrelated questions. The first, which you posed in the title, concerns the meaning of the English word "discrimination". The answer to that question is very simple: no, treating all students according to uniform standards and policies without consideration of their membership in various ethnic or racial groups is not discrimination; rather, it is precisely the *absence* of discrimination. That says nothing about whether it is a good or a bad (or moral/immoral, ethical/unethical etc) policy, it simply answers the question of whether it fits the meaning of a particular word in the English language.

Your second question was about how graduate students from minority and/or underprivileged backgrounds "should" be treated, which I interpret as asking about whether the policy of applying uniform standards to all students alluded to above is a good or a bad thing to have. This is a special case of a large set of questions associated with the terms [affirmative action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirmative_action) and [reverse discrimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_discrimination). It is a controversial topic that has been and still remains the subject of a large amount of debate as well as litigation, and if you care to learn more about it, there's a large body of discourse on such questions that you can find referenced in the Wikipedia articles linked above or with a google search. It is a sufficiently complex topic that I feel I can't meaningfully comment on it in a short post, and in any case enough has been said about it by people who have given the subject much more thought than I have to make anything I can think of saying about it laughably simplistic and uninteresting.

To clarify, this answer expresses no opinion about what policies should be in place for treating graduate students from underprivileged backgrounds.

Comment: _You are asking two separate and completely unrelated questions._ -- Agreed (and which is why I voted to close this question as unclear). I like your take on it, though (the _question_ even makes a little more sense now). +1

Comment: I like this alot, but I disagree with your definition of discrimination. If the standards you hold all students to are discriminatory in nature, then holding them to that standard is discrimination. Imagine a standard that all tests would be held on Fridays at sundown (a conflict between the standard and the Jewish faith). In Wales, forcing Welsh students to take tests in English, is a big one. A uniform policy might not allow animals into the classroom, but that would be discriminatory against individuals that need service animals.

Comment: @StrongBad you have a point, and maybe I was being a bit simplistic, but in my defense, I did not actually attempt to give a general definition of discrimination, I only opined that the specific things OP was asking about did not meet the definition. I agree that in principle, with enough bad faith even uniform policies could be devised that were in fact discriminatory in nature, and your examples do a good job of illustrating that, but I find them rather extreme and unrealistic, except perhaps the one involving Wales. I stand by my assessment that what OP asked about is not discrimination.

Comment: @StrongBad This is way too broad a definition of discrimination for practical purposes. What if some religion is against the idea of taking a test at all? What if the native langages of all students are different? What if I claim my goldfish provides me with emotional support? Should we make a test in 35 langages held on 6 different days with all animals allowed? Then it will be discriminatory to the one who needs to take the test at night, because their doctor said daylight negatively affects their performance. This cannot work as a society model.

Comment: @Zozor: There’s a big difference between your extreme examples and StrongBad’s reasonable ones.  As you say, it’s unfeasible to meet extreme and arbitrary requirements; but that’s no argument against aiming to accommodate reasonable and well-founded ones.

Comment: @MadJack: The question isn't particularly unclear though. OP has simply conflated two separate things. Closing the question and not answering it isn't going to particularly help OP with seeing the two separate sides of the question. If anything, OP's conflation of the two _helps_ with understanding the cause of OP's confusion; which actually helps with providing an answer (which, as Dan did, merely refers OP to existing discourse on a broad topic, while still answering OP's question as best as possible)

Comment: @StrongBad: Your example is highly contextual; it relies on the notion that exams are **mandatory** and **inevitably essential** (by design) to pass a class, and somehow also implicitly forbids justified absences (e.g. illness, emergency, religion)??? Loosening _any_ of the constraints you've added to the example drastically alters the problematic and supposedly discriminatory nature of the example. E.g. inviting all your friends to a lunch party for your birthday, which just happens to be during ramadan. Is that discriminatory towards your muslim friends? This is **very** subjective.

Comment: I think that is an unfair judgement. It is possible to ask the question of whether or not something should be done regarding to the policy of assessing or comparing graduate students with avoiding discrimination as a primary objective as in this case (though perhaps I was not sufficiently explicit in framing it). Thus I want to know if it can be somehow argued to be a discriminatory practice. This has nothing to do with whether or not it is moral or 'good/bad' to do so. There can be other ways to make it equitable for the underprivileged without damaging the integrity of the policy.

Comment: @Co3O4: Your question, and your latest comment here, **highly** depends on what you understand to be the definition of "discrimination". If you use a context-free dictionary definition (= to discern a difference), then holding minority students to different standards is **the literal definition of discrimination**. If, however, you are using a contextual definition (= to unfairly disadvantage a particular subset of people), then holding minority students to different standards is **an attempt to counter societal discrimination**. You need to disambiguate what you mean with "discrimination".

Comment: @Co3O4: As an easier example, the issue with the definition of "discrimination" that I'm trying to point out is similar to the semantical juxtaposition of being diagnosed as _HIV-positive_ (i.e. testing positive for the disease) not being a _positive_ (i.e. good, beneficial) state of health. A word can have different meanings in different contexts; and sometimes these two contexts cause a seemingly contradictory meaning.

Comment: Furthermore, should not be another type of discrimination robbing a more capable student(s) of their place in a course to "help" less capable students? Why making tests or entry interview then? As long as they tick the right boxes....

Comment: @PLL: I don't agree that my exemples are so extreme. It's fairly common to have classes with 20+ different native languages in international universities, and crazy religious requirements are commonplace too. My point is, at some point society needs to step in and say: OK, that's the rule, now you have to comply with it no matter what you think or what you are. Otherwise it just becomes crazy. Also, how do you draw the line between a reasonable and an "extreme" requirement? The goldfish guy will tell you that bringing his quiet and risk-free goldfish to the test center is nowhere near extreme.

Comment: @Zozor Have you had people say they are religiously against tests, and that their goldfish provides emotional support?

Comment: Zozor, for what it's worth, @StrongBad's example is not a theoretical situation only.  Workplace policies against head coverings of any sort are superficially non-discriminative, but in actual practice they can be ***and are*** used in places to discriminate against Sikh men and Muslim women (among others).

Comment: @AytAyt it wouldn't surprise me if a sect of Pastafarians were against tests and gained emotional support from goldfish.

Comment: https://www.economist.com/blogs/gulliver/2018/02/no-birds-allowed This happens all the time. For religious reasons it’s even easier to find, just google any cult with 10000+ followers and half of them will give you a good reason not to take an exam on a specified day or without a specific attire.

Comment: "The answer to that question is very simple: no, treating all students according to uniform standards and policies without consideration of their membership in various ethnic or racial groups is not discrimination; rather, it is precisely the absence of discrimination." This is incorrect. This can be a textbook case of indirect discrimination, and in some areas, it is prohibited by law. For instance, if you required everyone to attend a Christmas party where pork and beef was served, then you'd be discriminating against Hindus, Muslims, and Jews.

Answer (score 45):

It would be discrimination to not hold them to the same standard. It would not necessarily be fair on the underprivileged students,but where do you draw the line? Who's to say a "privileged" student has a benefit in a specific subject? If a privileged student is studying criminology to they get leniency on their grading for not having experienced as much crime? Who's to say their background hasn't helped them in other ways?

If you start grading based on a student's background you start to diminish the integrity of the course. "You only passed cause you're from a poor family".

Comment: Graduate school (excluding law school and medical school), for example in mathematics, is not much about grades, at all. The feedback loop is much more complicated, and much more individualized, in any case. People have wildly varying backgrounds, but/and can/do succeed in grad school. The successes need not be pre-scripted, and need not be identical. Mostly, no one "fails", etc.

Answer (score 28):

It is not discriminatory to expect that graduates of your program attain a certain standard of excellence, as determined by the (uniform) graduation requirements established by the program. It would be derilection of duty, however, to bring in a student substantially below your department’s expectations for incoming students without offering some mechanism or plan whereby the student can “catch up” with her peers. Note that this doesn’t mean you are obligated to move heaven and earth to do so—the student also bears significant responsibility for meeting the program requirements just like everybody else.

Comment: Big +1 for catch-up and not lowering standards.

Comment: I agree with @Mołot that catch-up is probably a much better mechanism than changing standards. The partial responsibility of department/advisor but also the student is a good point. This is the most relevant answer in the context of the question (i.e. graduate school).

Answer (score 17):

The only fair way is to assess abilities is to do the same way for everyone. This does not imply that you can't offer additional resources to students from underprivileged backgrounds (e.g., additional, Spanish-speaking tutors for Hispanic students) but in the end, you will have to apply the same standard when measuring ability or a diploma becomes meaningless: Did this student applying for X get an A because she was good, or because he was Hispanic?

Comment: It is not clear to me that the good version of this question is about "grading". It's about grad school, where smart people do not form a homogeneous population in any case, in terms of their quirks, background, specific talents, and so on. Grades are not good indicators, in my experience. Maybe you could usefully re-phrase your answer to not needlessly refer to "grades"? I hesitate to edit...

Comment: Fair point. I meant "grading" not in the sense of giving a grade on a scale from 0 to 100, but more in the sense of "ranking" or "assessing". I edited the post.

Answer (score 11):

*Is it discrimination?* No, as it is it's not discrimination. You're treating all the students equally, without discriminating between them, so it's rather the exact opposite.

However, unlike what some might think, "Am I treating everyone on an exactly equal footing?" is not the gold standard of ethical actions. For example, we can all agree that providing special bathrooms for people with reduced mobility and giving them priority access to these bathrooms is good, right? Well, *that's* discrimination, too! But good discrimination... (Which may be an oxymoron depending on your definition of "discrimination".)

You can't just say "it's not discriminatory" and be done with it. That's intellectual laziness and dishonesty. "Is it discrimination?" is perhaps one of the questions you should ask yourself, but certainly not the only one.

One problem is that the word discrimination is so negatively charged that people are reluctant to use it for situations where discrimination can be good, and try to contort words into meaning their opposite. But in the end it's not "discrimination" that matters, it's "are my actions moral?". But of course, it's much harder to answer, and many people take the shortcut. We're all different, and pretending that moral actions can only result from pretending that everyone is exactly the same is at best naive.

Comment: The answer is very well written and your point about intellectual laziness is very true, but unfortunately you’re also misusing the word “discrimination”, which according to the dictionary refers to _unjustly_ treating different groups of people differently. So hiring a smart person over a stupid person is not “discrimination of stupid people”; providing accessible bathrooms is also not discrimination; in general, there is no such thing as “good discrimination” - that would be an oxymoron - but there is such a thing as “good examples of treating people of different groups differently”.

Comment: ... So, as I said I think the core of your argument is valid, but your answer needs to be rephrased. For example, you can say “treating all people equally is not the gold standard of ethical actions”, etc.

Comment: @DanRomik I looked at two dictionaries, they said "treatment or consideration of, or making a distinction in favor of or against, a person or thing based on the group, class, or category to which that person or thing belongs rather than on individual merit" and "prejudiced or prejudicial outlook, action, or treatment" (where prejudiced is "resulting from or having a prejudice or bias for or especially against"). Yes, as I said the word is so negatively charged that it's usually understood as *unjust* discrimination. But really, the word says nothing about justice...

Comment: I think I found the one you used: Oxford dictionary? "The unjust or prejudicial treatment of different categories of people, especially on the grounds of race, age, or sex." It does say unjust *or prejudicial* (and prejudicial isn't always against, it can be for). Anyway I'm not a native English speaker so perhaps the nuances are lost on me (although in French "discrimination" has the same very negative connotation, even though formally it's not necessarily negative). I've edited my answer a bit.

Comment: interesting. I was referring to Merriam-Webster, which has a definition almost identical to OED.

Comment: @DanRomik Uh... [I don't see the word unjust there...](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discrimination) (That was in fact the second dictionary I used, which is why I was surprised! I wouldn't have gone to check otherwise...)

Comment: you’re right, sorry. I also checked a couple of dictionaries. The word “unjust” is specifically used in the dictionary definition given by my iPhone and google (“the unjust or prejudicial treatment of different categories of people or things, especially on the grounds of race, age, or sex.”) Also, to my understanding, “prejudicial” also encapsulates an element of injustice.

Comment: @DanRomik Frankly, I'd have to say that the iPhone's definition is not accurate in this case. Certainly, unjust discrimination is a type of discrimination (and not an uncommon one,) but not all discrimination is of that type. At best, that's a secondary definition of the word (as, in some contexts, unfairness could be implied.) "To discriminate" just means to make a choice or discern a difference between some set of things, though, without regard to whether the reasons are good or bad.

Comment: "You can't just say "it's not discriminatory" and be done with it." I disagree. Not *every* policy must be evaluated based on morality, not is it supposed to correct social inequality. Graduate school is quite different from basic education (K-12) in terms of purpose; it is also not a charity. Questioning the motives of the question as "dishonest" and "naive" from various assumptions is not conducive to a good answer.

Comment: @Co3O4 And yet you've just exposed your true motives: determining whether it fits the technical criterion of being "discrimination" if you follow some policy to the letter, rather than trying to know how to act morally. Graduate school is not a charity? So what? Does it give you a license to act unethically? Also, I wrote "*at best* naive". I had initially written "at best naive, at worst an active attempt to actually undermine people from a given background", but I thought at the time it was best to not assume bad intentions. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 7):

I disagree with the other answers. While on the surface, holding all students to the same standards sounds like the definition of fairness, if those standards are in fact discriminatory, then holding students to them is discrimination.

The simplest example I can think of is in Wales, students are allowed to take exams in either English or Welsh. Holding all students to a standard of taking exams in English (or Welsh) would clearly be discrimination against a group. One could argue that not allowing students to take exams in Spanish is also discrimination, and to an extent it is, but not all discrimination is illegal and not all groups are protected.

Another example would be to force students to take exams on Friday evenings. This would conflict with the Jewish Sabbath and cause issues for some students. Discrimination can also occur if the standard does not allow accommodations for individuals with disabilities.

Comment: Your examples are quite different. Moving an exam from Friday evening to accommodate for Shabbat will not influence the integrity of the course. Allowing to take an exam in Welsh will not influence the integrity of the course, *unless* it's a course on English language or literature. Where do we draw the line between a discriminatory standard and a required skill?

Comment: @svavil defining discrimination in general terms isn't hard, and strongbad gave the most considerate answer, but indeed the line-drawing is the difficult part. The further we get from the 'simple' world of ideal principles toward the complex and realistic world in which those are applied in practice, the more difficult and contested the answer becomes. Therefore I voted to close the question as too broad and off-topic. (In fact, it's also opinion-based.)

Comment: What you're describing is not discrimination, as Dan Romik says it is the exact opposite. Making accommodations for people based on their individual needs is, in fact, discrimination. The problem is that the word discrimination is negatively connoted, so people are reluctant to use it for such situations and try to contort words into meaning their opposite. For example, we can all agree that providing special bathrooms for people with reduced mobility and giving them priority access is good, right? Well, *that's* discrimination, too! But good discrimination...

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, "is it discrimination?" is a poor criterion. "Is it moral?", " Is it ethical?", "Is it legal?" etc are much better criteria. Focusing on one word, even a negatively charged one like "discrimination", is counter-productive. Otherwise you get, for example, people arguing that "they're not racist" because they're targeting a religious group instead of a "race" (← meaningless word), as if proving they're not "racist" solves everything. Similarly, proving "it's not discriminatory" doesn't solve everything. Sometimes it's even the opposite.

Comment: If I based my definition of academic standards on a curriculum taught in a school that only a minority attends, the majority would certainly claim that they are being discriminated against, despite only being held to the same standard.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi providing accessible access bathrooms is not discrimination, but making bathrooms non-accessible (or failing to make them accessible is). Giving priority access to any any group is discrimination. Rules that discriminate, whether intentionally or not, is discrimination even if those rules are applied equally to everyone.

Comment: @StrongBad You completely missed my point. We can argue all day whether providing only non-accessible bathrooms is worthy of the name "discrimination" or not. I say it doesn't matter what name you give to it (although I still think that the word "discrimination" does not fit, cf. a dictionary). What matters is that it's *bad*.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi note that I said that certain policies are the _absence_ of discrimination, not its _opposite_ - a distinction that I feel is important because of some of the valid points StrongBad raised (and which I already had in mind while I was writing my answer). But largely I agree with your side of the discussion more than with StrongBad’s position (I especially liked your last comment pointing out that which word we use to label a thing is less important than whether the thing in question is good or bad).

Comment: "...If those standards are in fact discriminatory, then holding students to them is discrimination" is an interesting argument; part of the reason why I asked this question in the first place is to see if it was possible for some interpretation beyond the dictionary one. I disagree with @henning that the question is too broad because it is applied specifically to graduate school competence. While I am inclined to agree that a particular standard for those with disabilities can be discriminatory, regular graduate students should have at least partial responsibility for their own competence.

Comment: This is by far the best answer. The source of OP's confusion (assuming they're not just trying to be bigoted) is that "academic standards" can actually encode discriminatory attitudes or conditions that systemically disadvantage certain groups of people rather than simply being "objectively academic".

Answer (score 2):

If you are assessing the students on the correct criteria then it is not discrimiation. However, often we judge people on a proxy for what we really care about.

So, for example, if I set an essay on the the structure/function relationship of the genome, I am trying to assess a students understanding of a particular section of biology. If I then give a poor mark to a student whose first language is not English because the quality of English is poor, this is discriminatory, because some groups of people have better/worst English, but this is not supposed to be the skill being assessed. However, if instead of biology, the programme was English, then it would not be discriminatory to assess the quality of English.

Similarly, I might want to assess how hard someone works by how often they are in the office between 9am and 5pm (yes, I know this is a terrible way to assess effort). But if someone is from a culture with a siesta, they might work 9am-1pm and again 3pm-7pm. They are working just as hard, but my criterion only works well for people of one culture.

---

The question about how to deal with resource allocation is more nuanced, and for me would be a question not of reward, but of who would benefit most.  So a student who doesn't yet have research to present probably would not benefit from travel to conferences as much as one who did. But for RA help, i would generally look at two student and go: this student is going to complete their project without extra help, where as this one is never going to finish without support. Thus the RA help would go to the one who needed it so that both students could get over the line.